# PHP MySQL Count Query Result is String, Not Integer

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**I have the following MySQL query, and PHP code to format the `Count` result in a single array:**

```
$equalDimensions_query = 
"SELECT 'allEqual' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight
UNION ALL
SELECT 'widthEqual' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight != $maxImageHeight
UNION ALL
SELECT 'heightEqual' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth != $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight";

$equalDimensions_data = mysql_query($equalDimensions_query) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($equalDimensions_data)) { 
    $cnt[$row['COL1']] = $row['imgCount']; 
}

var_dump($cnt);
```

(Notice I included `var_dump($cnt)` as the last line)

**The `var_dump` returned the following array:**

```
array
(
  'allEqual' => string '2' (length=1)
  'widthEqual' => string '0' (length=1)
  'heightEqual' => string '0' (length=1)
)
```

**I'm curious why the count is being returned as a string, and not as an integer?**

Should it be returned as an integer? Or is it the norm when dealing with count queries, for the result to be returned as a string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php:

> Returns an **associative array of strings** that corresponds to the
>   fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.

(emphasis mine) It's probably just easier for the MySQL driver to give you everything as a string, and assume you will know what to do with it. Just use [intval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)() to get the integer value.

Comment: Kudos for the link and the PHP to change the string into an integer. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is returned as a string¹, no matter if it's a column value (the column's type will not play any role) or the result of a function (the type of the return value will also not play a role).

¹when talking about the MySql driver, at least.

Comment: I see. So when I see integer values in associative arrays, they are not directly created from a mysql result?

Comment: @stefmikhail: Yes, it follows.