# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when using google chart

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a dashboard which uses google charts to display 2 pie charts, and a column chart, based on tickets raised by a user. Yesterday they were working fine, but this morning they are no longer loading.

After a bit of investigation, I found the issue is to do with my column chart, when I check the console I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

Digging a little deeper the error comes on line 192 of my code where I echo the 'reason' into the chart. 'reason' is a column name in my SQL table.

```
    $connect = odbc_connect("Description=PCD_SQL_SERVER;DRIVER=SQL         
    Server;SERVER=gbsuk0pcdspdsql","smtrfaUser","Summitdesk789");
    $query1 = "SELECT category, count(*) as Total FROM [SMT_RFA].[dbo]. 
    [smtJobTracker] GROUP BY category";
    $query2 = "SELECT status, count(*) as Total FROM [SMT_RFA].[dbo]. 
    [smtJobTracker] GROUP BY status";
    $query3 = "SELECT reason, count(*) as Total FROM [SMT_RFA].[dbo]. 
    [smtJobTracker] GROUP BY reason";

    $result1 = odbc_exec($connect, $query1);
    $result2 = odbc_exec($connect, $query2);
    $result3 = odbc_exec($connect, $query3);

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>SMT Track & Trace System</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/line-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--- Used for Model Search (AJAX / Javascript) --->
    <script src="js/formOne.js"></script>
    <script src="js/formTwo.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- jQuery jQuery Ajax Autocomplete Plugin For Input Fields -->
    <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);

    .logo
     {
     position: fixed;
     top: calc(100% - 65px);
     left: calc(100% - 135px);
     z-index: 10;
     }
     .containerWell{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: white;
      }
     body
     {
     background: #E8E8E8;
     font-family: Lato,'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
     }
    .card-body
     {
    padding-left: 150px;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body class="">

    <img src="img/MIS logo7-small2-gs.png" class="logo" style="height:40px;">

    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark py-3">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/sony-logo.png" class="my-2 
    my-lg-0" style="width:200px;"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
    target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor03" aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    </ul>
    <span class="navbar-brand"><h2 class="font-weight-bold" style="margin- 
    bottom: 0;text-shadow: 2px 2px black;">&nbsp; SMT Internal RFA</h2></span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav> <!-- navbar -->
    <div class="containerWell">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     Signed in as <?php echo $_SESSION['smtRequestForAction'] 
    ['user_name'];?><li> <a href=# onClick="pop()" id="logout"> Help </a> | <a 
    href="../../index.php" id="home"> Home  </a>| <a href="../logout.php" 
    id="logout"> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    <br>


    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartCategory);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartStatus);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartReason);

    function drawChartCategory() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Category', 'Total'],
      <?php
      while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result1))
      {
           echo "['".$row["category"]."', ".$row["Total"]."],";
      }
      ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'All tickets by Category',
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        backgroundColor: '#E8E8E8',
        pieSliceText: 'value',
        is3D: true
        };

    var chart = new 

   google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechartCategory'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawChartStatus() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Status', 'Total'],
      <?php
      while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result2))
      {
           echo "['".$row["status"]."', ".$row["Total"]."],";
      }
      ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'All tickets by Status',
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        backgroundColor: '#E8E8E8',
        pieHole: 0.27,
        animation: {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'in',
        startup: true
        }
    };

    var chart = new 
    google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechartStatus'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawChartReason() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Reason', 'Total'],
      <?php
      while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result3))
      {
           echo "['".$row["reason"]."', ".$row["Total"]."],";
      }
      ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'All tickets by Reason',
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        backgroundColor: '#E8E8E8'
    };

    var chart = new 

 google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchartReason')) ;

    chart.draw(data, options);
    }

   </script>

   <div class="container" id="containerChart" style="float:left;">
    <div class="pieCharts" id="pieCharts" style="width:1500px;">
      <div id="piechartCategory" style="width:50%; top:0px; float:left;"> 
  </div>
      <div id="piechartStatus" style="width:50%; top:0px; float:left;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pieCharts"  id="pieCharts" style="width:1500px">
      <div id="columnchartReason" style="width:50%; height:50%; top:0px; 
    display:inline-block;"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the error in my console.

[image: error in console]

Comment: You have a new line before the closing bracket

Comment: How can I remove it?

Comment: Instead of `echo "['".$row["reason"]."', ".$row["Total"]."],";` do `echo json_encode([$row['reason'], $row['Total']]).',';` -- this will make sure your generated JS code is valid with any input. To improve performance (if you feel like it matters), you can prepare complete data structure first, and then do single `json_encode` call.

Comment: @mat1986 literally just remove the newline from your source file. Having multiline string literals is invalid syntax in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, that's helped remove the error, when I load the page however, it now says 'Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string' where the chart should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clean the extra line produced by the database record using `str_replace()`, and since referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7463785/8566549), that MySQL count query result is returning a string, you could use [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to format the `$row['Total']` as integer :

```
  <?php
  while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result1))
  {
       echo "['" . str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $row["category"]) . "', " . intval($row["Total"]) . "],";
  }
  ?>
```